# What is Geralt's shoe size?

Tags: the-witcher

My friend happened to mention thinking "What would I do in Geralt's shoes?" and that got me wondering what his shoe size actually is.

I haven't read the books but I am doubtful any of them provides this info, so an estimate based on other media might be an option. Accepting any sources for an answer.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable, if not somewhat unusual request.

Comment: A comment with a negative vote would be appreciated so I can do better next time.

Comment: @AtsoS I haven't downvoted, but I suspect people are doing so because they think this question is too trivial and not useful. Of course, in a way *all* questions on this site are useless, but the tooltip on the downvote button does mention "not useful" as one of the crieria.

Comment: http://www.the-witcher-3.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/geralt_cosplay-guide.jpg

Comment: You do know that the "in their shoes" figure of speech does not literally mean that you, at your current size, wear the other person's shoes, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option is to try to determine Geralt's shoe size from other things we know about him.

### Estimate Geralt's shoe size from his height

This [brief statistical analysis](https://www.statcrunch.com/5.0/viewreport.php?reportid=35115) suggests that the best linear estimate of the relationship between height and shoe size is y = 50.874798 + 1.6565183x, where y is height in inches and x is shoe size. Inverting this equation, we arrive at x = 0.6036757y – 30.71188.

All the gaming websites seem to think Geralt's height is [around 180 cm](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150928104111AAANPVl), or 70 inches, or 5' 10". These are people who have actually played the game, so I'll go with that. **This gives us a shoe size estimate of 11.5.**

The correlation is only 0.6 or so, so this estimate could easily be off a bit.

Comment: If anyone knows a better estimate of Geralt's height, feel free to edit it in.

Comment: @anaranjada - A lot of the gaming websites think this is his height too. I might find a better estimate later.

Comment: Years later, I've accepted this answer to a somewhat embarrassing question. Better late than never.